Finding numbers that satisfy a cyclical identity between base 10 and base 16
A while back, I noticed an interesting identity that exists between two particular numbers, involving a cyclical shift of one number when represented in base $16$, so that it's equal to the cycled value in base $10$:
$$2008_{16} = 8200_{10} $$
In this case it involves cyclically shifting the LHS once to the right (I actually also posted a couple more examples in this community wiki post here about surprising identities).
More recently, a friend that got interested in the idea showed me the output a Python program he wrote, and it found several more identities by exhaustive search. To give a few examples:
\begin{align*}
 12575_{16} &= 75125_{10} && \text{ (2 cyclical shifts to the right)} \\
 15086_{16} &= 86150_{10} && \text{ (2 cyclical shifts to the right)} \\
 072468_{16} &= 468072_{10} && \text{ (3 cyclical shifts to the right/left)} \\
 036915494_{16} &= 915494036_{10} && \text{ (3 cyclical shifts to the left)} 
\end{align*}
Note that the last two can be taken as a weaker version of the identity, as it arguably employs a slight "cheat" of padding the base $16$ numbers with a zero to the left in that manner. Nonetheless they are also interesting.
My question is then, is there a quicker way than exhaustive search to find numbers that satisfy this cyclic relation, perhaps even a closed formula that can do that?
As an aside, I found out also that there's a similar concept of Cyclic numbers, and it seems like it may be related somehow. However, these don't involve comparing the representations of numbers in different bases like here.

You can reduce the amount of computation by removing possibilities that cannot work based on what you have so for.  For example, in five figures we have $10000_{16}=65536_{10}$ so any solution will have $0$ or $1$ for the first figure in base $16$ and if it is $1$ the leading figure in base $10$ must be at least $6$.  You can extend this as you build the number.  If you decide the leading digit in base $10$ is $8$, we have $80000_{10}=13880_{16}$ and $90000_{10}=15F90_{16}$.  The next digit in base $16$ must be $3$ to $5$ and we have accounted for three of the digits.  Now you don't have many choices for what the rotation is and you are down to just a few possibilities to check.  I used a similar strategy for my program that lead to 4494410 and friends.  I didn't describe it there, just used the results
If you don't allow leading zeros there are no solutions with more that five digits as $100000_{16}=1048576_{10}$
